# How to convert a List to variable argument parameter java

Tags: java, list, variadic-functions

I have a method which takes a variable length string (String...) as parameter. I have a `List<String>` with me. How can I pass this to the method as argument?

Comment: [Varargs In Java: Variable Argument Method In Java](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/varargs-in-java-variable-argument-method-in-java-5/)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. Is it `method(String... length)` or `method(int length, String... param)`, or maybe something else?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`String...` equals a `String[]`
So just convert your `list` to a `String[]` and you should be fine.

Comment: Additional note to OP: if you ever have a method that takes Object..., this scheme won't work because the String[] will be understood as one Object.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks. Any idea how to get around that?

Answer (score 42):

String ... and String[] are identical If you convert your list to array.

using

```
Foo[] array = list.toArray(new Foo[list.size()]);
```

or

```
Foo[] array = new Foo[list.size()];
list.toArray(array);
```

then use that array as `String ...` argument to function.

Comment: This also works: `list.toArray(new Foo[]{})`; useful if you don't want to store a list in additional variable.

Comment: What is this `Foo` thing ? I used a `String` instead as in `getUnsecuredPaths().toArray(new String[]{})`

Comment: Obviously this is an old comment, but to anyone else reading this who has the same question; `Foo` is a pretty common term used in programming as a placeholder for a value that can change. It is useful when you're providing a generic example such as the one above, as `Foo` can be replaced by whichever object you're working with (in this case, a String). You may also see `Bar` used when there are multiple placeholders in an example.

Answer (score 25):

You can use `stream` in java 8.

```
String[] array = list.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
```

Then the array can be used in the `...args` position.

Comment: list.toArray(new String[]{}) suffices

Comment: FYI, if developing for Android streams require API 24 and jdk 1.8, so make sure its set up in your manifest and project settings.

Answer (score 1):

in case of long (primitive value)

```
long[] longArray = list.stream().mapToLong(o->g.getValue()).toArray();
```

when `getValue()` returns a long type

Answer (score 1):

For Java > 8

You can very well use the `toArray` method very simply, as in:

```java
String[] myParams = myList.toArray(String[]::new);
```

Streaming becomes really interesting when the elements of the List must be transformed, filtered or else before being converted to Array:

```java
String[] myMappedAndFilteredParams = myList.stream()
                                 .map(param -> param + "some_added_stuff")
                                 .filter(param -> param.contains("some very important info"))
                                 .collect(toList())
                                 .toArray(String[]::new);
```