# Convert a Array of Strings to variable argument parameter in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

This is the same problem as described in the link

[How to convert a List to variable argument parameter java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748470/how-to-convert-a-list-to-variable-argument-parameter-java)

But how to do it with scala ?

I have a string which contains comma separated values .

```
val s =  "1.2.3.4,1.5.1.8,1.5.4.5,1.5.1.5"
```

I have converted to Array of String using

```
 val as = s.split(",")
 as: Array[String] = Array(1.2.3.4, 1.5.1.8, 1.5.4.5, 1.5.1.5)
```

The method expects a foo(String...param) which is actually a java method,but can be called from scala.

I tried `foo(as)` . But It din't work.

```
(x$1: <repeated...>[String])foo
cannot be applied to (Array[String])
```

How to convert the array of string to variable argument parameter ?